# A view controller is in landscape mode, but I'm getting the frame from portrait mode?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, viewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a settings view controller with a table view. The table view is supposed to set its frame to be the frame of the view controller. My app only supports landscape mode, so that's the orientation I'm always in.

However, when the settings view controller loads, the table view has the portrait mode frame of the view controller, even though it's in landscape  (360 by 480 when it should be 480 by 360).

Additionally, when I checked to see if the device thought it was in portrait mode, it returned true.

What is causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you call `[UIView init]` it will default to the screen size of your device in portrait mode (same goes for iPad but with larger size).
Inside `[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` the self.view will also default to this size.

Screen rotation is only done to the top view (controller) in your hierarchy and rotation messages are forwarded through container-VCs that support this behavior (e.g. UINavigationController, UITabBarController).

If you want your view to be sized correctly, use `[UIView initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]` for creating a view. Insinde UIViewController you only have the chance to override the loadView Method to set the frame before viewDidLoad gets called (or you could use a different XIB for landscape). You could also hardcode the view's size by setting its frame first thing in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewWillAppear to size your views before they display

Answer (score -2):

You have to implement this in your settings view controller:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }
```